# Free Way to do Expression Engine 2 Development?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm looking at doing some Expression Engine development, but it looks like with Expression Engine 2.x there is no longer the free Core version to download. This is for a single client as I don't normally do EE work.

Am I allowed to download their files/db to my local machine for development or will that be breaking any sort of license? Or am I expected to purchase a license even though I won't be running an EE site myself? The client has a full EE license, but I don't know that I want to drop $99 to build a basic module for a client.

Answer (score 2):

> An ExpressionEngine license purchase allows a single “live” installation in a production environment and ancillary “development use only” installations as needed to support the live installation (such as development and a staging servers).

ref: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/license.html

So, yes if you download the clients files/DB and install locally to continue the build or test with it, that's completely fine and within the license agreement.